# I can't get sessionToken from Parse

Tags: json, flutter, http, back4app

I want to Sign-Up my users with the help of  back4app.com and Parse RESTful API in my flutter app ,

this is my method :

```
 Future<void> signUpMethod(String username, String password) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://myshoppingapp.b4a.io/parse/classes/User');

   final response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {
          'X-Parse-Application-Id': kParseApplicationId,
          'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': kParseRestApiKey,
          'X-Parse-Revocable-Session':kRevoc,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          
          
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'username': username,
          'password': password,
        }));
```

but when users try to sign up I've got this from response body :

```
{objectId: DKSODF82aP, createdAt: 2021-06-17T20:51:26.312Z}
```

it doesn't contain any sessionToken and also in my back4app panel I don't have any entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using back4app, the URL you are using is incorrect.

The endpoint for signing up users is this

https://Your_server_url/users

So in your case, it would be
https://myshoppingapp.b4a.io/users

Also please remove the 'X-Parse-Revocable-Session' header and it's value value.

Comment: Thank's alot now it works and I've got sessiontoken

Comment: would you also help me about login Url enpoint? how to I send username and password to that url?

Comment: https://myshoppingapp.b4a.io/login
This will be your login url

Comment: You can just just send the username and password as JSON encoded in the body of the request like you did for signup